# How to get href value from selected element?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was recently writing a program to scrape links from "https://news.ycombinator.com/" but I've tried many methods and whenever I request the link it returns `None`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


response = requests.get('https://news.ycombinator.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text , 'html.parser')

links = soup.select('.titleline')
print(links[0].get('href'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the `<a>` to get the value of its attribute - Based on your selection from the question you only get the `<span>` and this do not have an attribute `href` so you have to reference the next `<a>`:

```
links = soup.select('.titleline')
print(links[0].a.get('href'))
```

or even better select it directly :

```
links = soup.select('.titleline a') ### to signify that the second element is matched if it has an ancestor that matches the first element.
### or 
links = soup.select('.titleline > a') ### to signify that the second element is matched if it has a parent that matches the first element    
print(links[0].get('href'))
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you got list of 'span' tags instead of 'a' tags.

You should change the line:

`links = soup.select('.titleline > a')`